# Can I create a Sequelize Object that corresponds to a view?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize with a SQL Server database. I need to create a Sequelize object that corresponds to a view.

The only "solutions" that I can find online are really just workarounds where you use a raw query rather than a Sequelize object. This really seems like functionality the Sequelize team needs to support. I cannot use the raw query work around so I was wondering if anyone knew of another, different work around/solution?

I should mention this view is legacy so I cannot create it from scratch. So if I try to create a model with the same name and attributes as the view I want to model, I get an error telling me that object already exists in the database.

Comment: It should work if you are using `sync` where `force:false`. If you are using `force:true` then I think you are between a rock and a hard place. Personally I only use `force:true` in my tests on an in-memory database. For staging/production I don't use `sync` at all and use Knex to update my schema's manually.

Comment: @AndrewEddie thanks for the suggestion! Using force: false got it to work when I created a simple Sequelize project just for this. Getting it to work in the context of my sails project will require a bit more tweaking, but at least I've proven it'll work locally.